# About Cantor set and the cluster set of points at the function $f$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness, limsup-and-liminf

I prefer to add picture in my question since this is not my proof. I was able to follow the proof but I lost the marked line when it said the cluster set of $a_n$ from the left is $[-1,1].$ This is equivalent to say that  $\{(a_n,x)\colon x\in[-1,1]\}$ is a subset of the limit points of the graph of $f.$ Notice that $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=0.$ Can we say also $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$ are limit points of the of $f$? let's just take $a_n=\frac{1}{3}$ and $b_n=\frac{2}{3}.$ since $f$ is continuous so the graph of $f$ is closed. Then, $(\frac{1}{3},-1)$ is limit point of the graph. My understanding for the marked line is that $\{(\frac{1}{3},x)\colon x\in[-1,1]\}$ is the limit point of the graph but this is not correct of course.

Any help will be appreciated greatly.   [image]

Comment: I have a request, namely that you tell us what theorem is being proved here, which would have helped for motivation. As it turns out, the Cantor set is one of my favorite mathematical beasts so I did not personally need that motivation, however I am really curious what the theorem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your case $a_n = \frac{1}{3}$, $b_n = \frac{2}{3}$, to understand the "cluster set of $a_n$ from the left" you need to consider a sequence of components of $I \setminus C$ which converge to $a_n$ from the left, namely:
$$\left(\frac{1}{9},\frac{2}{9}\right), \left(\frac{7}{27},\frac{8}{27}\right), \left(\frac{25}{81},\frac{26}{81}\right),\left(\frac{79}{243},\frac{80}{243}\right),\ldots
$$
The portion of the graph over each of these intervals is a line segment whose $y$-coordinate varies from $-1$ at the left endpoint to $+1$ at the right endpoint. If you sketch those line segments you will see that they are getting steeper and steeper, with slopes approaching $\infty$; the $\Delta x$ of each line segment is approaching zero, whereas the $\Delta y$ of each line segment is approaching $1 - (-1)=2$. Also, those line segments are accumulating on the segment
$$\frac{1}{3} \times [-1,+1] = \{(1/3,x) \mid -1 \le x \le +1\}
$$
which you observed in your post. Therefore, for each $x \in [-1,+1]$ you can choose a sequence of points
$$p_1 \in \left(\frac{1}{9},\frac{2}{9}\right), \,\, p_2 \in \left(\frac{7}{27},\frac{8}{27}\right), \,\,p_3 \in \left(\frac{25}{81},\frac{26}{81}\right), \,\,p_4 \in \left(\frac{79}{243},\frac{80}{243}\right), ...
$$
such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(p_n) = x$. In other words, "the cluster set of $a_n$ from the left is $[-1,+1]$".

**Added:** To see a bit more about how to choose the sequence $p_n$, I'll consider separate cases.

If $x \in (-1,+1)$ then $p_1 \in \left(\frac{1}{9},\frac{2}{9}\right)$ is uniquely determined so that $f(p_1)=x$, and similarly for $p_2,p_3,p_4$ and so on; thus, $f(p_n)=x$ for all $n$ and therefore $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(p_n)=x$.

If $x = +1$ then we have to choose $p_n \in (a_n,b_n)$ more carefully: choose
$$p_n = \frac{1}{n} a_n + \frac{n-1}{n} b_n
$$
Working through the algebra you will get
$$f(p_n) = \frac{1}{n}(-1) + \frac{n-1}{n}(1) = 1 - \frac{2}{n}
$$
and therefore $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(p_n)=1$.

If $x=-1$ then you can figure out a similar way to choose $p_n \in (a_n,b_n)$ so that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(p_n)=-1$.

Comment: Lee Mosher. Thank you . Basically, you choose  an increasing that converges to $ \frac{1}{3}$. Right ?. How did you see that $lim_{n\to\infty} f(a_n)=x.$ You used the $a_n$ for sequence and for the point. This is confused little bit .

Comment: Yes, that was a bad clash of variables, I fixed that; the sequence you choose is now called $p_n$. And then I added details regarding how to choose the sequence $p_n$.

Comment: And yes, you do choose an increasing sequence that converges to $\frac{1}{3}$, but not just any old increasing sequence that converges to $\frac{1}{3}$, because you have to make sure that evaluation of $f$ on that sequence converges to the given value $x \in [-1,+1]$.

Comment: Lee Mosher, I got confused again. Your sequence $p_n$ must converges to $\frac{1}{3}$. Right? but the second cases is not right. Right.? Also, in the first cases, not clear if the $p_n$ converges to $\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: Lee Mosher. About your request. The Theorem is to construct  a function such that $f$ has connected graph but is not almost continuous.

Comment: If you examine the sequence of intervals that I have constructed, and if you observe the pattern of that sequence of intervals, you will see that for **any** choice of $p_1 \in \left( \frac{1}{9},\frac{2}{9}\right)$, and for **any** choice of $p_2 \in \left(\frac{7}{27},\frac{8}{27} \right)$, and so on, the sequence $p_n$ that you obtain will converge to $\frac{1}{3}$ from below. This is true by application of the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Lee Mosher, Thank you so much for your nice answer.

Comment: Lee Mosher, Is the function $f$ in Baire class $2$?